# How to create a Sasl Scram user principal of Kafka by Go?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

Now I'm making a kafka service broker and want to create a new user when provisioning by using golang.
I've checked all kafka library of Go, But didn't find any way to create a user(principal).
It seems that two method below from Shopify/Sarama may be possible way, but I have no idea how to use it and could not find a sample code.

```
//AlterConfigsRequest is an alter config request type
type AlterConfigsRequest struct {
    Resources    []*AlterConfigsResource
    ValidateOnly bool
}
//AlterConfigsResource is an alter config resource type
type AlterConfigsResource struct {
    Type          ConfigResourceType
    Name          string
    ConfigEntries map[string]*string
}
```

What I want to do is: 
**`bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=myusername-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=myusername-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name myusername`**

Is it possible to call kafka-rest-api to create a user?
what is the best solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "kafka rest api"? Have you tried looking at the unit tests for that function?

Comment: 1.This is what i mean by "kafka rest api":
https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/quickstart.html

2.Yes, check:
https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/alter_configs_request_test.go

Comment: REST *Proxy* only maintains consumers and producers, not Zookeeper or external ACLs

Comment: And I think you missed this one https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/acl_create_request_test.go

Comment: Note that a `UserResourceType` is not available to map to `--entity-type users` https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/config_resource_type.go#L9-L21 so I think the only alternative is to use a Zookeeper golang library and add that data "manually"